# bazaar locations.conf does not exist

Tags: bazaar, bzr

I have just started using bazaar 2.4.1 and have been following through the documentation:

1. [Introducing Bazaar](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.4/en/user-guide/introducing_bazaar.html)
2. [Bazaar in five minutes](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.4/en/mini-tutorial/index.html)
3. ...continuing through chapter 1 and 2 creating repo's accordingly...

I got to [Configuring Bazaar](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.4/en/user-guide/configuring_bazaar.html#configuration-files) -> Configuration files

There it says

> Configuration files are located in ... C:\Documents and
>   Settings\ < username > \Application Data\Bazaar\2.0 on Windows. There are
>   three primary configuration files in this location:
>
> ```
> bazaar.conf ...
> locations.conf ...
> authentication.conf ...
> ```

I have had a look at that location. I can see `bazaar.conf` and `authentication.conf` but I cannot see any file called `locations.conf`.

Does `locations.conf` only get created when its needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I think locations.conf does not get created unless something wants to add data to it.

You can trivially create it yourself. It should exist in the same location as where bazaar.conf and authentication.conf live. An empty file has the same effect as no locations.conf file.